# Bootstrap table - split one of the row's column in two

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I managed to create 'double row' for a table in Bootstrap:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">B</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ideally I want it to look like this:
[image]

Playing around with `colspan` didn't really help, only broke things. I tried to set `colspan` of every row's first column to 2 and the one of B to 1, and have additional `<td>` for B1 and B2, didn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r6k51fby/5/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I've got a solution for you :

**SNIPPET**

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
thead{
  background:#C9E4F4;
}
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: center !important;
  border: 1.5px solid #929292 !important;
}
#text1 {
  background-color: #cac;
}
#text2 {
  background-color: #cca;
}
#navigation {
  background-color: #acc;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th colspan="2">1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The columns are correct, but if I understand correctly, `table-striped` should be replaced with a thead in color. (In the example, only the first row is colored)

Comment: @RamisWachtler Thanks a lot. I love that you actually took time and replicated the colours as well :)